# Associative Law in Propositional Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is this legal? (¬p∨q) ∨ (¬p∨r)  ≡ (¬p∨¬p) ∨ (q∨r)
The original question is (p⇒q) ∨ (p⇒r) ≡ p⇒(q∨r). I got to that first point by using equivalence of implications for both of the implications. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $\lor$ is associative and commutative. These are the two facts that you used in your calculation.